# Why all my numpad don't work?

Tags: 3d-view

It supposes when I press 1,3,7 the view will change automatically to top, side or bottom, but somehow it doesn't work. And then I find non of my numpad work. I'm using 2.8 by the way.

Comment: Check whether you have press Numlock on your keypad. Also, Windows can be configured to use the numeric jeypad for simulated mouse movement - check settings such as that.

Comment: Have you checked if your num lock in ON?

Comment: There is a caps lock but I didn't turn it on, the numpad 5 doesn't work either.

Comment: Capslock does nothing to numbers

Comment: Try enabling numlock

Comment: Thank for your answer but I think it must be sth else. Cuz I use the mac book. There is no numlock key...

Comment: See https://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/mac-tech-notes-phantom-numlock-stuck-keynote/  and http://osxdaily.com/2014/12/01/number-keys-not-working-mac-keyboard-fix/

Answer (score 1):

The number pad hot keys still work in 2.8. Have you remembered to re-apply emulate numpad in system preferences, because it is a new version of blender so the settings will be set to default (I made that mistake myself :) Also you can use the button next to the 1 to switch through lots of different views in 2.8. I think that may have been mentioned in the above answers. Hope I could have been of some help!

Answer (score 0):

nope. New shortcuts on 2.8, so forget about the 2.79 shortcuts. Though, if you want there´s a choice for 2.79 button config RIGHT on the FIRST install FIRST run of Blender to pick your right or left click select and your button configuration.
On a 3D VIEWPORT hold ALT+Drag the MIDDLE mouse UP (it will take you top view), do the same combinations with left, down, right for each viewport.

Thanks for voting my answer.

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: Thank you~It is much more convinent to control by mouse than press hotkey.

Comment: I use the MacBook Pro and I'm sure it has no NumLock key. So it must be something else... ...

Answer (score 0):

You can go to *Edit > Preferences > Input* and click *Emulate Numpad*.